# Simulator is so slow, but not when running with allocations?

Tags: xcode, performance, debugging, console, allocation

Really i dont know whats going on, ill explain.

First i have xcode 3.2.5, i've never managed to make allocation instruments and console working together, i still think its not posible ahahaha...

Anyways, when i run the app... its just sooooo slow... i checked console but everything seems normal to him... except that its 20 times slower. When i run with allocations, nothing appears in console... but it runs at normal speed... do someone may know whats going on??

Thanks in advance for your time!!!

Comment: The software run normal till i started to debug the bad acts of memory management that just started to making crush my app recently. I use databases of 300 or more rows and have like 300 images... maybe its something on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run the app with instruments,

1. The app will run really slow comparing the normal execution.
2. No logs will be printed on the console.

Comment: uhm, it runs slow with console... it runs normal with instruments. And  thanks for informing i wasnt crazy, i just read somewhere that you use the address given in console to search it in allocations...